# CakePHP - complex association

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am new to cake PHP, I have some problem

There are three Models: Guardian, Student and StudentFee.

**The relations look like this**: Guardian hasMany Student , Student hasMany StudentFee, StudentFee belongsTo Guardian, Student.

**My Problem** is the StudentFee detail is not getting inserted other than Student and Guardian details are inserted.

My Models are like

```
class Guardian extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Guardian';

    public $recursive =2;
    public $hasMany = array(
            'Student' => array(
                'className'     => 'Student',
                'dependent'     => true
            )
    );

}

class Student extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Student';

        public $hasMany = array(
            'StudentFee' => array(
                'className'     => 'StudentFee',
                'dependent'     => true
            )

    );
}

class StudentFee extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'StudentFee';
    public $belongsTo = array(
                    'Guardian' => array(
                    'className'     => 'Guardian',
                    'dependent'     => true
            ),
                'Student' => array(
                    'className'     => 'Student',
                    'dependent'     => true
            )
    );
}
```

In My controller I have used saveAssociated() like below code

```
$this->Guardian->set($this->request->data);
$this->Guardian->saveAssociated($this->Guardian->data, array('validate' => false));
```

Please help to resolve this problem, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's in your data? Also, a StudentFee should belong to a Student only, not a Guardian. It's already linked to a Guardian because StudentFee belongsTo Student, which belongsTo Guardian.

Comment: I need Guardian id in Student table and Student Id in StudentFee table or else Student Id and Guardian Id in StudentFee table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct for me   is:

### Models

```
// Guardian
    $hasMany = array(
      'Student' => array('clasName' => 'Student', 'foreignKey' => 'guardian_id')
    );

// Student
    $belongsTo = array(
      'Guardian' => array('clasName' => 'Guardian', 'foreignKey' => 'guardian_id')
    );

    $hasMany = array(
      'StudentFee' => array('clasName' => 'StudentFee', 'foreignKey' => 'student_id')
    );

// StudentFee
    $belongsTo = array(
      'Student' => array('clasName' => 'Student', 'foreignKey' => 'student_id')
    );
```

Your data (POST), maybe is like that:

```
[Guardian] => array(
),
['Student'] => array(
  [0] => array(
    ['StudentFee'] => array(
    )
  ),
  [1] => array(
    ['StudentFee'] => array(
    )
  )
)
```

So, just save:

```
// use the deep option to save items after the second level
$this->Guardian->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
```

I hope this help you.
Please try, and let me know if works.